# Subring of polynomial rings generated by a set

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, groebner-basis

I am thinking the generated subring of polynomial ring $K[X]$ where $K$ is a field. First I find that it is isomorphism to a quotient ring of $Z[Y]$. For example, let $S = \{f_1,f_2\}$ and $f_1, f_2\in K[X]$，and $I=\{g\in Z[y_1,y_2]|g(f_1,f_2)=0\}$. It can verify that $I$ is an ideal of $Z[y_1,y_2]$ and the subring generated by $S$ is isomorphism to $Z[y_1,y_2]/I$. Since $Z[y_1,y_2]$ is a Noetherian ring, $I$ is generated by finite elements of $Z[y_1,y_2]$ and there is a Gröbner basis $G$ of $I$.

My question is: how to compute the Gröbner basis $G$ for a given $S$? Is there some method or research about this?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think I would express the $P(a_n, \ldots)$ as a quotient of a polynomial ring in $\mathbb{Z}$, where $P = \mathbb{F}_p$ or $P = \mathbb{Q}$ is a minimal field and the $a_n, \ldots$ are the coefficients of the polynomials.  Then, apply the general procedure for using Groebner bases to find kernels of morphisms between polynomial rings.

Comment: So for example, if I want to find the kernel for $p_1(x) = \sqrt{2} x + \sqrt{3}$ and $p_2(x) = \sqrt{3} x + \sqrt{2}$, I calculate a Groebner basis for the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[s_2,s_3,x,p_1,p_2]$ generated by $s_2^2-2, s_3^2-2, p_1 - (s_2 x + s_3), p_2 - (s_3 x + s_2)$.  From the results of my CAS, I then get that the relations between $p_1,p_2$ are generated by $9p_1^4-12p_1^2p_2^2-6p_1^2+4p_2^4-4p_2^2+1$.  Is that along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I find that I can use the "Elimination theory" to get the kernel of $S$. But it is time consuming. Actually, I am studying the following polynomial set:
$$S = \{u_1 x_1^{i_1} y_1^{i_2} + u_2 x_2^{i_1} y_2^{i_2} + u_3 x_3^{i_1} y_3^{i_2}|i_1,i_2\in \{0,1,2\}\}.$$

Comment: And what I want to know is whether the following equation holds for some $n,{\alpha}_i$:
$$(u_1 x_1 y_1 + u_2 x_2 y_2 + u_3 x_3 y_3)^n = \sum {\alpha}_i \prod s_{i,j},$$
where $s_{i,j}\in S, {\alpha}_i\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\prod s_{i,j}\neq (u_1 x_1 y_1 + u_2 x_2 y_2 + u_3 x_3 y_3)^n$(otherwise, it is clear that it holds).
First the equation does not hold for all $n,{\alpha}_i$ if $S$ is algebra independent. 
But unfortunately, I find that $S$ is algebra dependent by the jacobian criterion.

Comment: So I try to find the kernel of $S$ to study the ring generated by $S$ directly. When I use Wolfram Mathematica to find the kernel, I find it is time consuming, in detail, there are still no results after computing about two days.
Anyway, thanks for your replying :).